# Creating Numpy Arrays of Images

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, image-processing

I have a numpy array of images in the shape of (200,1,50,50). This is 200 images of 50x50 images.

I am wanting to flip the a percentage of the images and save them in a brand new array. I can get the image out of the original array and flip it, however I can't figure out how to put the image into a new array (needs to be same shape as the original (x,1,50,50).

How do I go from (50,50) flipped image to an entry of (0,1,50,50) in a new array?

Comment: could you clear a bit of what do you mean by flip percentage ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add extra dimensions to you array, use the build-in function `expand_dims`. To flip an image use `cv2.flip`, after that you can crop your image as a post-processing step.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.random.randn(50, 50)

In [3]: x.shape
Out[3]: (50, 50)

In [4]: np.expand_dims(x, axis=0).shape
Out[4]: (1, 50, 50)

In [5]: x_ = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

In [6]: x_ = np.expand_dims(x_, axis=0)

In [7]: x_.shape
Out[7]: (1, 1, 50, 50)
```

Comment: You can have a numpy array with shape 0: `np.zeros(0).shape` gives `(0,)`. I don't think that's what the OP was asking for anyway though

Comment: I was referring to higher dimension array

Comment: Well, `np.zeros((0,1,50,50)).shape` gives `(0,1,50,50)` too.